# Why dojo.connect doesn't get fired after jQuery trigger?

Tags: jquery, dojo

I have two system, one of them is using Dojo and the other one jQuery. I have to make some connection between them, but I'm experiencing a problem.

jQuery eventlistener get fired after the jQuery trigger. Dojo event listener doesn't get fired. Why is that happen?

I have created a minimal environment from my current problem: http://jsfiddle.net/vEkt6/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="0" name="a" id="a" />
```

JS:

```
var el = dojo.byId('a');
dojo.connect(el, 'change', function(){
    console.log('dojo');   
});

jQuery(el).on('change', function(){
     console.log('jquery');   
});

jQuery(el).val(1).trigger('change');
```

Comment: http://blog.fgribreau.com/2010/08/jquery-fireevent-plugin-for-firing-real.html and https://github.com/FGRibreau/jQuery-plugin-fireEvent might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery bind events is complicated, basically it bind it with `addEventListener` (or similiar) and attaches additional info to data container of element. So it can't be used via pure js later. trigger works in similiar way - it will not trigger event binded by dojo. Dojo also do some tricks. To summarize, both frameworks uses dom level 2 to attach events, so you can't just call el.onchange(), it will be null. However, there is widely known piece of pure code which will do the trick:

```
var el = dojo.byId('a');
dojo.connect(el, 'change', function(){
    console.log('dojo');   
});

jQuery(el).on('change', function(){
     console.log('jquery');   
});

jQuery(el).val(1);

if ("fireEvent" in el) {
    el.fireEvent("onchange");
} else {
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
    el.dispatchEvent(evt);
};
```

[Your modified demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vEkt6/1/)

Comment: Thanks! I have used this piece of code (almost same, I have IE fallbacks) too in my Dojo codes for trigger, but I thought the jQuery trigger method do the same thing(my bad that I haven't checked the core code of jQuery). But it seems like that you are right, I should use this one...