# HTML Javascript Physical click triggers event but logical click doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, events, triggers, onclick

I've got this button:

```
<button class="dijitStretch dijitButtonNode dijitButtonContents dijitButton jStopThreads dijitButton" dojoattachevent="onclick:_onButtonClick,onmouseenter:_onMouse,onmouseover:_onMouse,onmouseout:_onMouse,onmouseleave:_onMouse,onmousedown:_onMouse" dojoattachpoint="focusNode,titleNode" type="button" wairole="button" waistate="labelledby-jStopThreads_label" role="button" aria-labelledby="jStopThreads_label" id="jStopThreads" tabindex="0" widgetid="jStopThreads" aria-valuenow="" aria-disabled="false" style="position: absolute; left: 76px; top: 528px; z-index: 3; width: 104px; height: 20px;"><span class="dijitInline " dojoattachpoint="iconNode"><span class="dijitToggleButtonIconChar">✓</span></span><span class="dijitButtonText" id="jStopThreads_label" dojoattachpoint="containerNode">
```

When I physically click on that button, the desired event triggers right, but It doesn't when I do using jQuery this way:

```
$('.jStopThreads').trigger("click");
```

or

```
$('.jStopThreads').click();
```

The button clicks because it focuses, but the event associated isn't triggered? How is this possible???

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5002478/5247200) about triggering events with dojo. And maybe add _Dojo_ to the tags because it is the origin of the issue.

Comment: Read also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16104337/5247200)

Answer (score 0):

That's because jQuery can only trigger events, which were added via jQuery.
So, if you would add the event via jQuery like this:

```
$('.jStopThreads').click(function() {
  // the content of your function
});
```

It could later be called via the jQuery functions trigger() or click()

Comment: Or events that were added inline `onclick="doSomething"`

Comment: The button has already an onclick event. When I click on it, it triggers an event (inherited from an awful ide which i hate). What I need to achieve is to trigger that event with javascript/jquery instead of a physical mouse click...

Comment: As benjarwar wrote below: Your event was not added in the jQuery context, so unfortunately it is not possible to trigger it via jQuery. Please have a look at the reading material David suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a library, Dojo, to attach your click event. Do it in jQuery:

```
function clickHandler(e) {
    alert('clicked!');
}

$('.jStopThreads').on('click', clickHandler);

$('.jStopThreads').trigger("click");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: The button has already a click handler! I just want to know why the button handles the physical click but the logical click! What you are doing in the code is adding other click handler which executes but the event attached to the button isn't triggered.

Comment: It doesn't have a click handler registered via jQuery. And then you're trying to trigger the click with jQuery. So, actually, in the context of jQuery, your button *does not* have a handler. Also, maybe relax with the exclamation points, you sound angry and frustrated, which isn't going to help us to help you.

Comment: So jQuery only triggers "click" if a jQuery click listener is registered? Sorry if I sound frustrated, but i'm actually, I'm in this for hours and can't solve it. Thanks.